# Struggling to get low battery notifications with i3?

Tags: i3-wm

I am using ubuntu 22.04.

I use i3 and tried to install i3-battery-popup.

I added this to my i3/config but it doesnt work.

`exec --no-startup-id i3-battery-popup -n -D -L 20 -l 10`

Is there a better solution?

I am using an Asus Rox Strix laptop.

Comment: were you able to find a solution for this. I am facing the same problem where it works when i just run it as a script but doesn't work when i put it in the i3 config